# How to get database off of localhost and running permanently?

Tags: reactjs, database, neo4j

So not sure it this is stupid to ask, but I'm running a neo4j database server (using Apollo server) from my React Application. Currently, I run it using node in a separate terminal (and I can navigate to it on localhost), then run npm start in a different terminal to get my application going. How can I get the database just up and running always, so if customers use the product they can always access the database? Or, if this isn't good practice, how can I establish the database connection while I run my client code?
Technologies being used: ReactJS, Neo4j Database, GraphQL + urql

I tried moving the Apollo server code into the App.tsx file of my application to run it from there directly when my app is launched, but this was giving me errors. I'm not sure if this is the proper way to do it, as I think it should be abstracted out of the client code?

Comment: Hello, there are several ways to start a Neo4j instance separately, even locally: Neo4j Desktop, Docker, etc. For provisioned online services, you've got Neo4j sandbox and Neo4j AuraDB. Is this the kind of information you are looking for?

Comment: if you already have some kind of server you can run it at system boot with task scheduler on windows or shell script on linux. You don't have to manually open terminal and run command while the system can do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run your server in the cloud so that customers can access your React application you need two things:

1. one server/service to run your database, e.g. Neo4j AuraDB (Free/Pro) or other Cloud Marketplaces https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/cloud-deployments/
2. A service to run your react application, e.g. netlify, vercel or one of the cloud providers (GCP, AWS, Azure) that you then have to configure with the server URL + credentials of your Neo4j server

You can run `neo4j-admin dump --to database.dump` on your local instance to create a copy of your database content and upload it to the cloud service. For 5.x the syntax is different, I think `neo4j-admin database dump --path folder`.